# php array Сложные массивы и поиск в другом сложном массиве

Tags: php, массивы

Блин не могу ускорить работу скрипта, помогите пожалуйста ускорить скрипт, ну и конечно же явные мои ошибки тоже распишите.
смысл в том что есть массив($array) в нем нет площадей они по нулям, все площади есть в другом массиве($array_all) надо заменить все нули на площади
скрипт работает, из-за массивности не доходит до логического конца, сервер выдает ошибку HTTP ERROR 500 спустя минут 10 работы скрипта

```
    $array_all = explode("\r\n", file_get_contents('A1621_all_ZN.csv')); //325кб ~14000 строк
    $array = explode("\r\n", file_get_contents('A1621.csv')); //1915кб ~14000 строк
    $ftp_path='/var/www/html/gagarin/xls/A1621_last.csv';

$fp = fopen($ftp_path, "a")or die('no connect');

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $array_line[]= explode(";", $value);
    if ($array_line[$key][7]==0.000000) {
        foreach ($array_all as $a_key => $val) {
            $array_all_line[]= explode(";", $val);
            if ($array_all_line[$a_key][1] == $array_line[$key][8]) { 
                $result = $array_all_line[$a_key][0];unset($array_all_line[$a_key]);  break;
            }


        }

        $array_line[$key][7]=$result;
    }
    foreach ($array_line[$key] as $key1 => $value1) {
        if ($key1==0) {
            $write_line=$value1;
        }else{
            $write_line.=';'.$value1;
        }
    }
    fwrite($fp, $write_line.PHP_EOL);

    unset($array_line[$key]);

}
```

Огромное спасибо пользователю Peresada за комментарий, он мне очень помог!
Вот код решения моей проблемки

```
$A1621='/var/www/html/gagarin/xls/A1621.csv';
$A1621_all_ZN='/var/www/html/gagarin/xls/A1621_all_ZN.csv';
$A1621_last='/var/www/html/gagarin/xls/A1621_last.csv';

unlink($A1621_last);

$A1621_open = fopen($A1621, "r")or die('A1621');
$A1621_all_ZN_open = fopen($A1621_all_ZN, "r")or die('A1621_all_ZN');
$A1621_last_open = fopen($A1621_last, "a+")or die('A1621_last');

while (($A1621_open_data = fgetcsv($A1621_open, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {

    while (($A1621_all_ZN_open_data = fgetcsv($A1621_all_ZN_open, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {

        if ($A1621_all_ZN_open_data[1]==$A1621_open_data[8]) {
            $A1621_open_data[7]=$A1621_all_ZN_open_data[0];
            break;
        }

    }

    fputcsv($A1621_last_open, $A1621_open_data,";");
}

fclose($A1621_open);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Массивности тут никакой нет, 14к строк для csv файла - это менее секунды обработки. Проблема в Вашем скрипте

**Во-первых**, для чтения csv файлов уже давно есть `fgetcsv` - она будет работать явно быстрее, чем несколько `explode`

**Во-вторых**, для записи csv существует функция-антоним `fputcsv`

**В-третьих**, если записывать в файл не 1 строку, а пачкой, например в 100 строк, то скрипт будет работать быстрее. Для этого используйте кеширование

**В-четвертых**, разобраться в Вашем коде крайне сложно с нашей стороны, так как мы не видим данные, которые Вы обрабатываете, кроме того, Вы не пытаетесь писать так, чтобы код можно было нормально прочитать.

Имхо, первые 2 пункта уже решат Вашу проблему, 3-4 пункты - нужны, чтобы не залезть в еще большую кучу.

**Update** А слона то я и не приметил:`$array_line[]= explode(";", $value);` - у Вас каждая итерация увеличивает массив $array_line, хотя по логике не должна, дальше догадаетесь?